# What actually is a jump in assembly and how does it work?

Tags: assembly

What actually is a jump in assembly and how does it work?
Can you provide me any example?

Comment: A jump is an instruction that modifies the `PC` (`Program Counter`), also called `IP` (`Instruction Pointer`). This is a register which determines where the next instruction is read from.

Comment: What part of the documentation did you not understand?

Comment: What instruction set?

Answer (score 2):

Programs are too large to be stored in the CPU, so they are stored in memory.  As a consequence of that, each machine code instruction in a program has a memory address / memory location.

The processor is an interpreter of instructions: it processes one instruction after another, continuously.  We can think of it as executing an instruction stream, and, that is what a program is (oversimplified of course as programs have both code and data).

The program counter is the fundamental device that controls the sequencing of execution — it is an pointer-sized register that holds the address of machine code instructions.  It determines the instruction stream that the processor executes: most instructions advance the program counter by their own size, such that after one instruction executes, the processor will automatically execute the next sequential instruction in memory.

Programs interact with the program counter.  Loops typically move the program counter backwards (towards lower memory address) so as to repeat some code already executed (but with different state, such that the loop has some purpose / ultimate objective).  Conditionals, like if-then-else interact with the program counter in order to skip forward, i.e. to skip over the then part (in order to execute the else part), or, skip over the else part (after executing the then part).

In order to properly control the instruction stream, there are two kinds of branches on the processor: conditional and unconditional.

An if-then-else statement decomposes as follows

```
...
if ( condition ) 
    then-part
else 
    else-part
...
```

---

```
    ...
    if ( ! condition ) goto else1; // skip ahead to the else when condition is false
    then-part
    goto endOfIf1;  // skip over the else part, since we just ran the then part
else1:              // where to go when the condition is false
    else-part
endOfIf1:           // where to go when the if statement has concluded
                    // regardless of whether the then or the else fired..
    ...
```

The `if () goto ...` construct is a conditional branch, and almost all processors have some capability of doing this as a machine code instruction.

The `goto ...` (without the preceding `if`) is an unconditional branch, and almost all processors can do this as well.

Branches can usually go backwards or forwards, and they are put into code sequences to control the flow, to tell the processor to repeat some code or skip ahead.

In the intel world, the program counter is call the instruction pointer, and this the same concept as the program counter in the non-intel world.